# Defining CRS for objects in Kyrgyzstan

Tags: coordinate-system, coordinates

We are currently working on two cities in the South of Kyrgyzstan (Aydarken and Kadamjay).

They are visible on the map screenshot below (purple dot). For reference, the grid is Lat/Long WGS84 (DD).

[image: Example]

Now we received a set of coordinates with an uncommon syntax unknown to us, see screenshot below.

[image: New_Coordinates]

And to make things tastier, EPSG and units used are obviously unknown.

We are currently digging for more details/metadata, but for the moment we simply know they come from a governmental statistics office in Kyrgyzstan.

This syntax is unknown to me. I tried a "brute force" conversion to DMS, DDM and DD, simply by splitting the coordinates and setting them as WGS84.

As you can see, they end up in Kazakhstan (being, in this case, 44°N) - while we know they are supposed to be in southern Kyrgyzstan.

Therefore, **there are hypothesises**:

1. Error in source data (wrong coordinates)
2. The wrong method, these are coordinates in a specific format/unit/EPSG, which I need to identify

**Questions:**

1. What means can I use to identify unknown units format/syntax and deduce the right EPSG? I have a look at [EPSG.io](https://epsg.io/) but the dozen of CRS identified for Kyrgyzstan do not match the syntax and I am lost in the thousands of others.
2. Has anybody seen similar coordinates before? Data looks quite old, so could be an old Kyrgyzstan or russian CRS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely this is UTM 42N, EPSG 32642: https://epsg.io/map#srs=32642&x=701911&y=4426789&z=9&layer=streets

Comment: It is indeed! Should have checked before. Thanks a lot for the answer, fast and clear ! :-)